# CSS dropdown menu - whole bar is moving

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am quite desperate about this. I guess it's just some stupid mistake - however, I am quite newbie and I can't see it now.

I am creating a wordpress theme with Underscores framework and my dropdown menu is not behave the way it should. The whole bar is moving down when I use the dropdown.

Here's demo:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuk26.jpg)

The menu bar should be of course fixed at the top of the page. Here's the CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
.main-navigation,
.main-navigation.toggled {
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    min-height: 3em;
}

.nav-menu {
    padding: 0.3em 0 0 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.main-navigation ul,
.main-navigation.toggled ul{
    max-height: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-navigation.toggled ul{
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.main-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    outline: 1px solid #333;
}

.main-navigation li li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.main-navigation a {
    min-width: 14em;
    max-width: 23em;
}

.main-navigation a,
.main-navigation ul ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul.toggle-on {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12em;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 0;
}


.main-navigation ul ul ul.toggle-on {
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
    min-width: 14em;
    max-width: 23em;
}

.main-navigation.toggled:after {
    display: none;
}

}
```

Classic wordpress menu:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Menu', 'hitchdiary' ); ?></button>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try giving position fixed in main-navigation class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the result by adding "vertical-align:top" property to the list item

```
.main-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped :) I also had to add fixed height of .main-navigation  and it works now.